# Does the unit passed to the datetime64 data type in pandas do anything?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, datetime64

Does the unit passed to the datetime64 data type in pandas do anything?

Consider this code:

```py
import pandas as pd 
v1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64'})
v2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64[ns]'})
v3 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64[ms]'})
v4 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64[s]'})
v5 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64[h]'})
v6 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64[D]'})
v7 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64[M]'})
v8 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-01']*1000}).astype({'Date':'datetime64[Y]'})


for v in [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8]:
    x = v.iloc[0,0]
    print(x, type(x), x.to_datetime64(), v.memory_usage()['Date'])
```

It returns:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
2020-01-01 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000 8000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: The *Pandas* version of the `datetime64` type only timezone support. Specifically, when you try to a `datetime64` variant in a Pandas series, it'll only support `as` (attosecond), `fs` (femtosecond), `ps` (picosecond) and `ns` (nanosecond) resolutions, anything less precise is replaced by `datetime64[ns]`. The `datetime64[<res>, <tz>]` variant only accepts `s` (seconds), `ms` (milliseconds), `us` (microseconds) and `ns` resolutions. Don't confuse these with the [`numpy` datetime64 type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

For both Pandas and Numpy, the 2-letter abbreviation determines the *resolution* used to record the timestamps, and because the type is always stored as 64 bits, it determines the range of values you can store in it. It does not alter how much memory the type takes!

From the [numpy `datetime64` *Datetime Units* documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units):

> Datetimes are always stored with an epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00. This means the supported dates are always a symmetric interval around the epoch, called “time span” in the table below.
>
> The length of the span is the range of a 64-bit integer times the length of the date or unit. For example, the time span for ‘W’ (week) is exactly 7 times longer than the time span for ‘D’ (day), and the time span for ‘D’ (day) is exactly 24 times longer than the time span for ‘h’ (hour).

Your experiment won't show any difference in memory use, because the amount of memory doesn't change, only the resolution.

Because Pandas *wraps* the numpy `datetime64` type, and you can't actually create a series with anything other than `datetime64[ns]`; e.g. the [`DateTimeIndex` `dtype` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex) is documented as accepting either a *`numpy.dtype` or `DatetimeTZDtype` or `str`, default `None`*, but that for `numpy.dtype` there is an additional restriction:

> Note that the only NumPy dtype allowed is ‘datetime64[ns]’.

So to demonstrate what the effect of different units, you'd have to use the `numpy` type directly:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> for unit in ('Y', 'M', 'W', 'D', 'h', 'm', 's', 'ms', 'us', 'ns'):   # ps, fs and as have too small a span
...     print(unit, np.array(["2021-02-27T12:24:17.524627869"], dtype=f"datetime64[{unit}]"))
...
Y ['2021']
M ['2021-02']
W ['2021-02-25']
D ['2021-02-27']
h ['2021-02-27T12']
m ['2021-02-27T12:24']
s ['2021-02-27T12:24:17']
ms ['2021-02-27T12:24:17.524']
us ['2021-02-27T12:24:17.524627']
ns ['2021-02-27T12:24:17.524627869']
```

**Note**: The *documentation* for Pandas only ever talks about `ns` resolutions for the `datetime64` types, and it appears from various issues on GitHub that while some of the codebase supports the other (finer) resolutions, this support is not reliable or widely supported by everything in the library. Your mileage may vary.